# How to check if part of a folder name exist in a list of directoryinfo?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This part in the script:

```
string savedGamesFolder = string.Format("{0}/Saved Games",
            Application.persistentDataPath);
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(savedGamesFolder);
        var savedGameFolder = new DirectoryInfo(savedGamesFolder);
        var directories = savedGameFolder.GetDirectories().OrderBy(d => d.CreationTimeUtc).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < directories.Count; i++) 
        {
            if (directories[i].FullName.Contains(LevelButtonItem.saveSlotNumber))
            {
                var files = Directory.GetFiles(directories[i].FullName);
                saveLoad.Load(files[1]);
            }
        }
```

On this line the saveSlotNumber is "SaveSlot1"

```
if (directories[i].FullName.Contains(LevelButtonItem.saveSlotNumber))
```

the folder on the hard disk structure like this:

C:\Users\test\AppData\LocalLow\DefaultCompany\testinggame\Saved Games\SaveSlot0 SavedGameSlot_1920x1080_2023-06-15_14-04-08

The problem is that there is a  folder containing SaveSlot1 but there are also directories containing SaveSlot10 and SaveSlot11 and 12 and 13 and more. since saveSlotNumber is SaveSlot1 then SaveSlot1 appears in many other directories names.

How to check for the specific directory if the saveSlotNumber is part of it then using contains?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SceneFader : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region FIELDS
    public GameObject fadeOutUIGameobjectImage;
    public float fadeSpeed = 3f;
    public SaveLoad saveLoad;
    public bool fadeEnded = false;

    private Image fadeOutUIImage;
    private DirectoryInfo lastDir;

    private void Start()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += SceneManager_sceneLoaded;
    }

    public enum FadeDirection
    {
        In, //Alpha = 1
        Out // Alpha = 0
    }
    #endregion

    #region FADE
    public IEnumerator Fade(FadeDirection fadeDirection)
    {
        fadeOutUIGameobjectImage.SetActive(true);

        float alpha = (fadeDirection == FadeDirection.Out) ? 1 : 0;
        float fadeEndValue = (fadeDirection == FadeDirection.Out) ? 0 : 1;
        if (fadeDirection == FadeDirection.Out)
        {
            while (alpha >= fadeEndValue)
            {
                SetColorImage(ref alpha, fadeDirection);
                yield return null;
            }

            fadeOutUIGameobjectImage.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            fadeOutUIGameobjectImage.SetActive(true);

            while (alpha <= fadeEndValue)
            {
                SetColorImage(ref alpha, fadeDirection);
                yield return null;
            }

            fadeEnded = true;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region HELPERS

    public IEnumerator FadeAndLoadScene(FadeDirection fadeDirection, string sceneToLoad)
    {
        if (SaveGameManual.manualLoading == false || LevelButtonItem.manualLoading == false)
        {
            yield return Fade(fadeDirection);
        }
        else
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneToLoad);
    }
    private void SceneManager_sceneLoaded(Scene arg0, LoadSceneMode arg1)
    {
        MenuController.newGameClicked = false;

        if (MenuController.LoadSceneForSavedGame == true)
        {
            if (saveLoad == null)
            {
                saveLoad = GameObject.Find("Save Load").GetComponent<SaveLoad>();
            }

            if (SaveGameManual.manualLoading)
            {
                saveLoad.Load(GetLastDir());// <<<<<
                SaveGameManual.manualLoading = false;

            }

            if (LevelButtonItem.manualLoading)
            {
                GetDirsFiles();
            }
        }
    }

    private void SetColorImage(ref float alpha, FadeDirection fadeDirection)
    {
        if (fadeOutUIImage == null)
        {
            fadeOutUIImage = fadeOutUIGameobjectImage.GetComponent<Image>();
        }

        fadeOutUIImage.color = new Color(fadeOutUIImage.color.r, fadeOutUIImage.color.g, fadeOutUIImage.color.b, alpha);
        alpha += Time.deltaTime * (1.0f / fadeSpeed) * ((fadeDirection == FadeDirection.Out) ? -1 : 1);
    }
    #endregion

    private void GetDirsFiles()
    {
        string savedGamesFolder = string.Format("{0}/Saved Games",
            Application.persistentDataPath);
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(savedGamesFolder);
        var savedGameFolder = new DirectoryInfo(savedGamesFolder);
        var directories = savedGameFolder.GetDirectories().OrderBy(d => d.CreationTimeUtc).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < directories.Count; i++) 
        {
            if (directories[i].FullName.Contains(LevelButtonItem.saveSlotNumber))
            {
                var files = Directory.GetFiles(directories[i].FullName);
                saveLoad.Load(files[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    private string GetLastDir()
    {
        string savedGamesFolder = string.Format("{0}/Saved Games",
            Application.persistentDataPath);
        lastDir = new DirectoryInfo(savedGamesFolder).GetDirectories()
                       .OrderByDescending(d => d.LastWriteTimeUtc).First();

        var files = Directory.GetFiles(lastDir.FullName);

        return files[1];
    }
}
```

Update:

this seems to be working. not sure 100% but it looks like it's working.

```
private void GetDirsFiles()
    {
        string savedGamesFolder = string.Format("{0}/Saved Games",
            Application.persistentDataPath);
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(savedGamesFolder);
        var savedGameFolder = new DirectoryInfo(savedGamesFolder);
        var directories = savedGameFolder.GetDirectories().OrderBy(d => d.CreationTimeUtc).ToList();


        string regexPattern = $@"\\{Regex.Escape(LevelButtonItem.saveSlotNumber)}\b";
        Regex regex = new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        foreach (var directory in directories)
        {
            if (regex.IsMatch(directory.FullName))
            {
                var files = Directory.GetFiles(directory.FullName);
                saveLoad.Load(files[1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

should i post it as answer?

Comment: sounds like you need regular expressions

Comment: @BugFinder I edited my question with what I try and I think it's working.  does it looks the right way using regular expressions ?

Comment: You could change the path formatting to something that is easier to distinguish, such as putting an underscore after the save number. eg. `"SaveSlot0_SavedGameSlot...."` then you can do `fileName.StartsWith("SaveSlot0_")`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're actually hitting is not the name pattern recognition, that one is just a consequence of the actual problem (and the fact that you're over-engineering it): you need to load a saved game from a slot. So here is a solution:

1. Fetch all slots from I/O,
2. Present them to user in a way you'd like the most (assign an id 0..N to each slot and button etc.),
3. Make button event to call a function and pass an id to it, and it will load the file from already known path.
   Profit.